# Excel VBA Worksheet loop - How to move through n worksheets

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Here is a simple loop that is copying a range to another location on the same worksheet.  This also needs to loop through all the remaining worksheets and perform the same copy paste values.  My use of variable "Dim ws" in the loop is suspect.

```
Sub UpdateSPCData()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case UCase(wsLoop)
    Case "Data - MOAQ", "Report" 'Do nothing
    Case Else
        Range("H2:H5").Copy
        Range("I2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End Select
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `wsLoop`? Your loop makes no reference to `ws` so will always refer to the active sheet.

Comment: That's a good question.  It is borrowed code.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this. Also, if checking upper case names you must make sure you are comparing with upper case text.

```
Sub UpdateSPCData()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case UCase(ws.Name)
    Case "DATA - MOAQ", "REPORT" 'Do nothing
    Case Else
        ws.Range("H2:H5").Copy
        ws.Range("I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: SJR, Thank you.  I should have been more patient and read through the code.  It never pays to be in a hurry at work.  Regards, David